# making zeromq client server concurrent using asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, client-server, python-asyncio, zeromq

I am trying to write a client server in python using zeroMQ using concurrent model (asyncio)

I have the server code `server.py` below.

```
import zmq


class Server:

    def __init__(self, port_number):
        self.context = zmq.Context()
        self.socket = self.context.socket(zmq.REP)
        server_url = "tcp://127.0.0.1:" + str(port_number)
        self.socket.bind(server_url)

    async def receive(self):
        while True:
            msg = await self.socket.recv()
            print("Got", msg)
            self.socket.send(msg)
```

I have the client code below `client.py` below

```
import zmq


class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.context = zmq.Context()
        self.socket = self.context.socket(zmq.REQ)

    def connect(self):
        self.socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5000")
        self.socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:6000")

    async def send_msg(self):
        for i in range(10):
            msg = "msg {0}".format(i)
            await self.socket.send(bytes(msg, 'utf-8'))
            print("Sending ", msg)
            await self.socket.recv()
```

The code that calls the client and server in asyncio mode is given below.

```
import asyncio
import time
from server import Server
from client import Client
import logging


async def server(port_num):
    logging.info('Starting server on port 5000')
    s1 = Server(port_num)
    await s1.receive()


async def client():
    logging.info('Starting client')
    c1 = Client()
    c1.send_msg()


async def main_thread():
    await asyncio.gather(server(5000), server(6000), client())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = time.perf_counter()
    logging.info("Main    : before creating thread")

    asyncio.run(main_thread())

    logging.info("Main    : before running thread")
    elapsed = time.perf_counter() - s

    print(f'{__file__} finished executing in {elapsed:0.2f} seconds')
```

When I run the program waits infinitely at `await s1.receive()` in the function

```
async def server(port_num):
    logging.info('Starting server on port 5000')
    s1 = Server(port_num)
    await s1.receive()
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import and use `zmq.asyncio` to create the ZeroMQ context.

```py
import asyncio
import zmq
import zmq.asyncio

ctx = zmq.asyncio.Context()
```

Comment: sorry, there was another bug in my code. you suggestion worked. Thank you very much